# Are Japanese translations for "Pearl Harbor" ever used metaphorically?

Tags: translation, metaphor

In English, "Pearl Harbor" is sometimes used [metaphorically](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pearl_Harbor#Noun) to indicate an unannounced attack, or an event that strongly changes the outlook of a community. Can these metaphorical meanings be used in Japanese with either "真珠湾" or "パールハーバー"? For example, "This action was no Pearl Harbor - we knew it was going to happen"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and Kamikaze either, which is synonymous to 天佑 or something like miraculous fortune unless <s>they're</s> it's used as a loan word.

Comment: Kamikaze being used in a loan word like "神風タクシー"?

Comment: What's that?...I mean when we refer to foreign usages.

Comment: a description of kamikaze taxis during the 1964 Olympics - http://theolympians.co/2015/06/09/kamikaze-taxis-in-tokyo-in-1964-hard-to-believe-today/

Comment: Such usage of kamikaze/banzai as an adjective meaning "suicidal, reckless" is unique to English, I think.